# Counting the Number of Element Comparisons in Quick Sort

Tags: c++, sorting

I have been provided this predefined code for Quick Sort which isn't to be altered much:

I know we already have questions on this but this is different as the logic is predefined here.

```
void quicksort(int a[], int l, int r)
  {
    if (r <= l) return;
   /* call for partition function that you modify */ 
    quicksort(a, l, i-1);
    quicksort(a, i+1, r);
  }

int partition(int a[], int l, int r)
  { int i = l-1, j = r; int v = a[r];
    for (;;)
      { 
        while (a[++i] < v) ;
        while (v < a[--j]) if (j == l) break;
        if (i >= j) break;
        exch(a[i], a[j]);
      }
    exch(a[i], a[r]);
    return i;
  }
```

We are just required to make slight modification so that the quicksort returns the number of comparisons that it, and partition function together (in total) have performed in sorting the given array a. **In these comparisons, only the comparisons that involve array elements are counted. You are not allowed to use any global variable in counting these comparisons. **

I have implemented this as follows, kindly let me know if I'm mistaken somewhere:

```
int partition(int a[], int l, int r, int& count) {
    int i = l - 1, j = r; int v = a[r];
    for (;;) {
        while (a[++i] < v) count++;
        while (v < a[--j]) {
            count++;
            if (j == l) break;
        }
        if (i >= j) break;
        swap(a[i], a[j]);
    }
    swap(a[i], a[r]);
    return i;
}


int quickSort(int a[], int l, int r) {
    int count = 0;
    if (r <= l) return 0;
    int i = partition(a, l, r, count);
    return count + quickSort(a, l, i - 1) + quickSort(a, i + 1, r);
}
```

Once you confirm, I'm going to share a surprising result of my research on this with you.

Comment: That's obviously incorrect, since you throw away the return values of the recursive calls to quickSort. The outermost quickSort only returns the comparison count of its own single call to partition.

Comment: Global variables for the win!

Comment: @CaptainGiraffe: Pfah. `return count + quickSort(a, l, i-1) + quickSort(a, i+1, r);`

Comment: @CaptainGiraffe: Oh yes, my bad. Really  sorry. Using global variables is not allowed in this problem. Sorry.

Comment: My apologies. My comment was made in jest.

Comment: @CaptainGiraffe: Oh right...what was I thinking. I have edited the code now as per the suggestion made by you. Thank you so much. Is the code totally fine now?

Comment: Now for the surprising result....

Comment: When I used this code to experiment with various inputs, **turns out that the number of comparisons made for a random list and a partially sorted list is about half the number of comparisons made in a fully sorted list.** Now, this is totally opposite of what one would expect. How come?

Comment: Make the sorted list 10 times the size and sort them again.

Comment: I'm working on it. Are you sure I have incremented the count in the right place(s) in the partition function?

Comment: I ask this because I can easily implement my own quick sort but the structure of the existing code is hard to grasp for me, especially the partition function. I'm just not sure if I incremented the counters at all the right places.

Comment: @CaptainGiraffe: Ok...can you please run me through the partition code. I cannot understand it at all. I know what a normal partition function should do but this one has empty for loop and a while loop that does nothing...I'm confused. I think it's from Robert Sedgewick's book.

Answer (score 0):

ricis comment works fine as a solution. There is an alternate approach one might take that can be generalized to the std::sort and other algorithms, and that is to make a counting comparer.

Something along the lines of

```
struct CountingComparer{
    CountingComparer():count(0){}
    CountingComparer(const CountingComparer& cc):count(cc.count){}

    bool operator()(int lhs, int rhs){  
        count;  
        return lhs < rhs; 
    }

    size_t count;
};
```

Now you need to change the signature of your function to add the comparer as a last argument. Like

```
template<typename COMP>
void quicksort( .... , COMP comp){
```

And the same change to the partition function. The comparisons are then made by

```
 while (comp(a[++i],v))   and
 while (comp(v, a[--j])) respectively.
```

### Calling the sort

You need to make sure you have a reference to your comparer in the template argument.

```
CountingComparer comp;
quicksort(...  , std::ref(comp));
```

Makes sure comp is not copied.

After the sort you find the number of comparisons in comp.count.

### regarding your comment on counts

Your quicksort's  behaviour is extensively discussed on the wikipedia page. It is expected that a sorted array behaves badly, while random elements behaves well.

### Regarding the cleverness in the partition function

```
for (;;)
  { 
    while (a[++i] < v) ;
    while (v < a[--j]) if (j == l) break;
    if (i >= j) break;
    exch(a[i], a[j]);
  }
exch(a[i], a[r]);
```

- The first for statement isn't really counting anything so thats just a while(true) in disguise. It will end by a *break* statement.
- Find the first large element to swap: The `while (a[++i] < v);` statement takes advantage of the fact that the pivot `v or a[r]' element is the rightmost element. So the pivot element acts like a guard here.
- Find the first small element to swap: The `while (v < a[--j]) if (j == l) break;`  does not have the guarantee of the pivot. Instead it checks for the leftmost limit.
- The final check is just to see if the partition is done. If so break out of the infinite loop and finally
- `swap(a[i], a[r]);`, arrange the pivot element to its correct position.

Comment: I see. Thank you. In my partition function, however, is the placement of the count incrementers correct?

Comment: Ok...can you please run me through the partition code. I cannot understand it at all. I know what a normal partition function should do but this one has empty for loop and a while loop that does nothing...I'm confused. I think it's from Robert Sedgewick's book.

Comment: @GuptillGunther It looks exactly like the code in Sedgewick. I'll comment on it in the answer. It is a clever way to not have to do two comparisons in each while.

Comment: @GuptillGunther Made a few edits to explain the partitioning a little bit more. Have a good day =)

Comment: @CaptainGiraffe: You comparator object depends on being passed by reference, but there is no guarantee of that in the standard library (and your sample code doesn't do it, either). It's better to associate the counting comparator to a boxed counter (i.e. a pointer to a long or size_t)

Comment: @CaptainGiraffe: Thank you so much for your effort explaining. I really appreciate it. You're a champ!